# How to share post on google plus from android app without shareIntent?

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-signin, android-sharing

I follow googleplus docs to share post using shareIntent But I want to share post without starting Intent. is it possible? 
Any Hint apppreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can share your post using authorized tokens in google plus. Please go through the [link](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/posts/creating).It will help you